# error: no matching function for call to ‘MyClass4::MyClass4()’ and error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘printdata’ with no type [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;


class MyClass4 {

int num1;
double num2 ;

public :
MyClass4(int x , double y);
printdata();


};

MyClass4::MyClass4(int x, double y){

num1 = x ;
num2 = y ;


num1 = 3 ;
num2 = 4.6 ;
}

MyClass4::printdata(){ 

cout <<"The Number 1 is ; "<< num1;
cout <<"The Number 2 is ; "<< num2;

return num1;
return num2 ;
}



int main(){

MyClass4 test ;

return 0 ;

}
```

The error is in these lines :

```
  MyClass4::printdata(){
```

Which the error says "error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘printdata’ with no type [-
fpermissive]"

The second one would be

```
  MyClass4 test ;
```

and the error i got is  "error: no matching function for call to ‘MyClass4::MyClass4()’"

Comment: whats the return type of `printdata` ?

Comment: btw `return` returns from the function. The second `return` cannot be reached

Comment: For the printdata, the return type should be integer

Comment: The constructor is declared like `MyClass4(int x , double y);`, so when constructing an object it expects an int and a double. For example `MyClass4 test(1, 3.0);`

Answer (score 0):

Your `printdata` method is missing a return type. Aside from constructors and destructors, every function and method needs a return type. in your case the definition should look like `int printdata();` and the declaration `int MyClass4::printdata() {...}`. What's more, you're returning twice inside the method but the function doesn't continue after the first return so the second one's never reached.